# User editable properties with varying number of arguments

Tags: c#, winforms

Recently I used this pattern to create a list of properties, each property having a varying number of arguments.

The properties list can be made at compile time, it does not need to change at runtime.

I tried to code this in a way such that it was easy for me to edit to add in additional properties (i.e., easy to add in a "Video Card" with arguments "Brand", and "Cost").

This would be part of an application, e.g., this could be implemented by having a "property editor" dialog which showed the property name, and 3 text boxes with labels showing the names of the properties they are editing.

- The constructor for `clsProperty` has a lot of exceptions it can throw, it's probably not necessary since this can only be changed at compile time, but I put them in for completeness and to demonstrate what could go wrong if there was a typo in the code that made the properties list; let me know if you think there is a better way to do error handling in this case. It would be nice to have at least some sort of warning if the parameters aren't right but I'm not sure if exceptions are the right thing to use here.
- I think I saw that a list of Object is usually frowned upon, let me know if this is a valid time to use that, or if there is an alternative in this case.
- Any general suggestions to improve readability would be helpful too.

For the sake of this example assume that everything in `clsProperty` is for display purposes only, no code will be doing something like `if(Property.Name == ...)`

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace csParseTest
{
    internal class clsProperty
    {
        // is it worth making these fields into properties of clsProperty?
        internal readonly   string          Name;        

        internal readonly   List<string>    ArgNames       = new List<string>();
        internal readonly   List<Type>      ArgTypes       = new List<Type>();
        internal readonly   List<Object>    ArgDefaults    = new List<Object>();

        private List<Object> ArgValues = new List<Object>();

        internal clsProperty(string iName, List<string> iArgNames, List<Type> iArgTypes, List<Object> iArgDefaults)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(iName))
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Property must have a valid name.");
            }

            this.Name = iName;

            bool tParameterLengthsOK =  (
                                            (iArgNames.Count == iArgTypes.Count) && 
                                            (iArgTypes.Count == iArgDefaults.Count)
                                        );

            if (!tParameterLengthsOK)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Each argument must have a name, type, and default value.");
            }

            for (int tArgumentIndex = 0; (tArgumentIndex < iArgNames.Count); tArgumentIndex++)
            {
                string  tArgName        = iArgNames[tArgumentIndex];
                Type    tArgType        = iArgTypes[tArgumentIndex];
                object  tDefaultValue   = iArgDefaults[tArgumentIndex];

                if(tDefaultValue == null)
                {
                    throw new ArgumentException("Argument " + tArgumentIndex + ": no default value.");
                }

                if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(tArgName))
                {
                    throw new ArgumentException("Argument " + tArgumentIndex + ": name must not be blank.");
                }

                if (!IsValidArgType(tArgType))
                {
                    throw new ArgumentException("Argument " + tArgumentIndex + ": type " + tArgType.ToString() + " is not supported.");
                }

                this.ArgNames.Add(tArgName);
                this.ArgTypes.Add(tArgType);
                this.ArgDefaults.Add(tDefaultValue);
                this.ArgValues.Add(tDefaultValue);
            }
        }

        internal void SetArgument(int iArgIndex, string iValueString)
        {          

            if ((iArgIndex < 0) || (iArgIndex > (ArgValues.Count - 1)))
            {
                throw new IndexOutOfRangeException("Argument index " + iArgIndex + " is invalid, arguments list has " + ArgValues.Count + " items.");
            }

            Object  tValue      = null;
            Type    tArgType    = this.ArgTypes[iArgIndex];

            if (TryParseArgValue(iValueString, tArgType, out tValue))
            {
                this.ArgValues[iArgIndex] = tValue;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Could not parse string " + iValueString + " as argument type " + tArgType.ToString());
            }
        }

        // for the sake of this example assume that properties can only be one of these types.
        internal static bool IsValidArgType(Type iType)
        {
            return
                (
                    (iType == typeof(System.String))  ||
                    (iType == typeof(System.Int32))     ||
                    (iType == typeof(System.Int64))    ||
                    (iType == typeof(System.Single))   ||
                    (iType == typeof(System.Double))
                );          


        }

        private static bool TryParseArgValue(string iValueString, Type iParseAsType, out object qValue)
        {
            qValue = null;

            if (iParseAsType == typeof(System.String))
            {
                qValue = iValueString;
                return true;
            }
            else if (iParseAsType == typeof(System.Int32))
            {
                int tParsedInt;
                if (int.TryParse(iValueString, out tParsedInt))
                {
                    qValue = tParsedInt;
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }

            }
            else if (iParseAsType == typeof(System.Int64))
            {
                long tParsedLong;
                if (long.TryParse(iValueString, out tParsedLong))
                {
                    qValue = tParsedLong;
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }

            else if (iParseAsType == typeof(System.Single))
            {
                float tParsedFloat;
                if (float.TryParse(iValueString, out tParsedFloat))
                {
                    qValue = tParsedFloat;
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }

            else if (iParseAsType == typeof(System.Double))
            {
                double tParsedDouble;
                if (double.TryParse(iValueString, out tParsedDouble))
                {
                    qValue = tParsedDouble;
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // I considered throwing an exception here
                return false;
            }

        }
    };


    class Program
    {
        // for the sake of this example assume that this properties list does not need to be changed at runtime.
        private static readonly List<clsProperty> AllProperties = new List<clsProperty>
        {
            new clsProperty("Optical Drive",    
                            new List<string>    {"Brand",                   "Speed",                "Format"},    
                            new List<Type>      {typeof(System.String),     typeof(System.Single),   typeof(System.String)}, 
                            new List<Object>    {"Asus",                    220.3,                  "BD-ROM"}),

            // or with named parameters...
            new clsProperty(iName:"Hard Drive",  
                            iArgNames:new List<string>      {"Type",                        "Price"},    
                            iArgTypes: new List<Type>       {typeof(System.String),         typeof(System.Double)}, 
                            iArgDefaults: new List<Object>  {"Solid State Drive",           123.4})

        };

        // test code
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // e.g., user edits values using text boxes (or a data grid maybe),
            // then hits OK or apply
            AllProperties[0].SetArgument(0, "Lite-On");
            AllProperties[0].SetArgument(1, "100.9");
            AllProperties[0].SetArgument(2, "DVD-ROM");

            //Properties[0].SetArgument(1, "ShouldFail");
            return;
        }


    }


}
```

EDIT: This would be using Winforms for the GUI

Comment: Rather than having three separate lists (one for names, one for types, and one for values), it would probably be better to have just one list, where each item in the list contains a name, a type, and a value. Also consider using a dictionary instead of a list, because looking up strings in a dictionary is both faster and easier than looking them up in a list.

Comment: Just wondering, were you referring to the input parameters to the constructor, the class's internal fields, or both? Also, you're right that a dictionary could help access properties by name, but for right now the only thing needed is access by index.

Comment: To expand on what @TannerSwett said, I'd probably use a `Dictionary<string, Tuple<Type, Object>>`. I'm just curious though. What's the purpose of this code? What problem are you trying to solve? If we knew the reason you felt the need to write this, we may be able to provide a completely different alternative. (Possibly something using `dynamic`, but I don't know...)

Comment: @jrh I was referring to both. Though, as a bit of a counterpoint, the constructor might be easier to use if it takes a list (or even an `IEnumerable`) instead of a dictionary.

Comment: @RubberDuck Not sure if this helps, but this is going to be used as part of a game modding tool application, these properties are used to  edit how an entity behaves in the game. E.g., "Health", 100; some properties have multiple Attributes (e.g., "DamageFactor" "Fire", 2.0). There's at least a couple hundred different properties to pick from.

Comment: And why wouldn't you just write the appropriate classes @jrh? At least you'd have some static typing to help you avoid bugs. The solution you have here is going to be much more susceptible to runtime errors.

Comment: Extremely relevant reading: [The Object](http://thecodelesscode.com/case/167)

Comment: Note: Discussion continued in Chat http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/29867558#29867558

Comment: After messing around with PropertyGrid, in my opinion the control has less than stellar usability, I would recommend a custom solution (though not the one I posted in this question).

Comment: @Downvoter -- what was the issue with this post?

Comment: After quite a bit of time working with a camelCase system, I'm not particularly thrilled that it adds even more emphasis to a rather opinion based "what is a word" system, some examples off the top of my head, "XMLFile" vs "xmlFile" vs "XmlFile", "fileName" vs "filename", "Login" vs "LogIn", "Username" vs "UserName", "Password" vs "PassWord", see also [Atwood's "The Case For Case Insensitivity"](https://blog.codinghorror.com/the-case-for-case-insensitivity/). Though that probably means using a prefix system for telling the difference between parameters, member fields, and properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it about web or windows UI? WPF or WinForms: you could just use [PropertyGrid](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.propertygrid(v=vs.110).aspx) - it is the same component you have in Visual Studio to edit properties. To define properties at runtime if happens to be needed - see [TypeDescriptor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.typedescriptor(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: A PropertyGrid seems like a good fit for this case. RubberDuck mentioned in chat that I could use metadata to make properties with user-friendly, translatable name attributes. When I wrote this, I wasn't aware of how much you could do with metadata, or that there were controls that could access it, so this is pretty cool! I'm still not completely sure where metadata is stored, or the best way to make it work with a resx file, but this is probably the direction I'm going to go in.

Comment: Yep, you can find a lot about this [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/356464/localization-of-displaynameattribute), [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2138/Globalized-property-grid) or _Chapter 11 Properties Window_ in this [book](https://www.amazon.com/Windows-Forms-Programming-Chris-Sells-ebook/dp/B004X1VVTQ). You can do a lot there.

Answer (score 4):

**Naming**

Your names are a little confusing. Arguments are what you're passing into methods or applications. What you're calling arguments here are normally called properties or attributes.

Class names start with a capital letter by convention, so that would make `ClsProperty`.

I wouldn't use abbreviations here - `ClassProperty` is just a few characters longer and reads a lot nicer. I'm not sure if it's a very descriptive name though - but without knowing more about the context in which it will be used it's hard to suggest a better name.

I assume the `i`, `t` and `q` prefixes stand for 'argument', 'local' and 'out' respectively? Personally I don't use such prefixes - to me they add little value, nothing that a descriptive name and a mouseover in a decent IDE doesn't tell me. Either way, when you change a local variable to an argument you'll have to update its prefix too, and that's easily forgotten, which makes these kind of prefixes less reliable over time.

`SetArgument` doesn't set an argument (attribute), it sets the *value* of that argument, so `SetArgumentValue` would be a better name.

**Code structure**

Don't use separate lists for things that belong together - create an `Attribute` class that contains a name, type, default value and current value. It'll make your code easier to understand and to maintain. For example, you no longer have to deal with lists of different length, and horizontally aligning names, types and default values is no longer necessary either.

A `ClassProperty` probably shouldn't have multiple attributes with the same name, so storing attributes in a dictionary (using their name as key) and checking for duplicate names would be a good idea.

`ClassProperty` is already marked as `internal`, so you don't need to mark its properties as `internal` again. Doing so signals that they're not meant to be used by external code. You may actually want to make those lists (or that dictionary) private, and expose those attributes via a read-only array or `IEnumerable` property instead, so outside code can access and modify all attributes but can't add, remove or replace any.

**Initialization**

You can use the `params` keyword if you want to call a method (or constructor) with a variable number of arguments (it's syntactic sugar for creating an array at the call-site):

```
// Constructor signature:
public ClassProperty(string name, params Attribute[] attributes) { ... }

// Call with as many or as few Attribute arguments as you want:
new ClassProperty("Optical Drive",
    new Attribute("Brand", typeof(string), "Asus"),
    new Attribute("Speed", typeof(float), 220.3),
    new Attribute("Format", typeof(string), "BD-ROM"));
```

Alternately, you can let `ClassProperty` implement `IEnumerable` and give it an `Add` method so you can use initializer syntax with it:

```
new ClassProperty("Optical Drive") {
    new Attribute("Brand", typeof(string), "Asus"),
    new Attribute("Speed", typeof(float), 220.3),
};
```

I'd prefer the `params` approach however, as it doesn't clutter the interface of your `ClassProperty` class. You also mentioned that new attributes won't be added at run-time, so it may not be desirable to have an `Add` method anyway.

**Type safety**

Your initialization code does not check if a given default value is valid for the specified attribute type. With a little use of generics, you can enforce correct typing at compile-time:

```
// Static method in Attribute:
public static Attribute Create<T>(string name, T value)
{
    return new Attribute(name, typeof(T), value);
}

new ClassProperty("Optical Drive",
    Attribute.Create<string>("Brand", "Asus"),    // <- fine
    Attribute.Create<float>("Speed", "BD-ROM"));  // <- compile error!
```

**Other notes**

Your use of type-names is somewhat inconsistent. Since `System.String` and `string` refer to the same type, I would just use `string` everywhere - it's less verbose and everyone's familiar with it anyway. The same goes for the other `System.*` types.

`TryParseArgValue` contains a fair bit of code. You could simplify this by using `Convert.To*` methods instead of `*.TryParse` methods. If an exception is thrown, simply return false. `Try*` methods don't throw by convention, so you were right by deciding to return `false` for unsupported types.

Documentation! Attributes can only use a select few types, and `null` is not a valid default value. That's the kind of thing you want to put in the summary docstring of the relevant class or method.

Comment: Thanks for looking through it. I think an attribute class is a good idea; would it be better to make a new Attribute every time its Value is changed (in this case would a mutable class be good practice?), or should I use Attribute.SetValue() or something similar? Another question, if I used generics, how would I access the type of the attribute when doing Convert.To*?

Comment: Also regarding "Properties" / "Arguments" naming, I'm using the naming from the program I'm exporting this "configuration file" to. For the prefixes: part of it is that I go back and forth between VB.NET and C# and case isn't enough to differentiate between instances and definitions. The tiq prefix thing I admit might only help me.

Comment: I would only make the value of that attribute class mutable. If it's immutable you'll need to replace attributes, which allows calling code to set a new name or type. Preventing that then requires additional checks... which is making things more complicated for no real gain. As for generics, I don't think there's much value in making the attribute class itself generic. A generic helper method that creates non-generic instances (as shown above) is sufficient in this case.